# how to parse an xml file and link it to an edittext in android

Tags: java, android, xml

i need your help guys on something ,, i'm creating an app on android, it's based on an idea of an app i created on PC using java eclipse ,, when i input the starting point and the ending point and click on get routing it gives me the street names and distance etc ,, i created the XML file for those points and the streets names and distances etc it's like this :

http://pastebin.com/UtTMNE8g

how to parse it ,, that when i type inside the editText,, the application knows the points .

Comment: You can checkout this link: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/ and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html

Comment: thanx @DanCantir i'll try with both of the links , thank you so much

Comment: There are different flavors of parser available, such as `Sax`, `Stax`, or `Dom`... you can get help here http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/parsing-xml-using-dom-sax-and-stax-parser-in-java.html

Comment: @Mithun thank youuu sooo much for the link ,, you two guys inlighted me i was stuck on this stupid app ,, thank youuu guys soo much

Comment: i have a question to ask ,, i have my app when i click on a button it shows an alert dialog with a text field ,, i want it when i type a point name in the alert dialog it compares it with the xml data ,, how to do it ?